# Do I need to release after finishDecoding using NSKeyedUnarchiver?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nskeyedarchiver

Is finishDecoding also handling the release of the NSKeyedUnarchiver instance? 
It doesn't say in the [Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedUnarchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to handle it yourself.
You can easily verify it in [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/decoding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000950-BAJBIGJC), look at the examples, both methods (`finishDecoding` and `release`) are called.

Comment: You are right, thank you. The problem I'm having is that when releasing, the contents in my NSMutableArray is lost. 
_connectedSystems = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:kSystemsDataKey];
[unarchiver finishDecoding];
EEMSystem * system = [_connectedSystems objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@", system.name);
This gives me the name.
However, if I add [unarchiver release]; after [unarchiver finishDecoding]; I doesn't work.

Comment: @Man of One Way - curious indeed, but this can not be related to the simple call of the `release` method. I suggest you ask another question giving a code snippet, to find out what it is.

Comment: The problem must be when I run - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder and passing [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:kEEMSystemNameKey]; to my string. I need to alloc a NSString first, otherwise the NSString *name in my system will point to something in the archiver, which will then be gone once released.

Comment: @Man of One Way - yes, I definitively think the problem isn't (or partially) related to `release`, but it's hard to tell, with seeing just a few instructions. Also, `release` is just used as with all others objects.

Comment: @Man of One Way - no, no need to alloc the string first, the unarchiver gives you a well formed standalone object, you should only care about retain it (or copy maybe for a string).

Comment: Yes, I did retain it, another problem arises. But that's another issue though, thank you.